# How to echo text into a file in a new column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

For example i have a file named 1.txt which contains:

```
Windows 7
Windows 8
Windows 8.1
Windows 10
```

and 2.txt which contains:

```
2009
2012
2012
2014
```

and I want to echo 2.txt into 1.txt like this:

```
Windows 7     2009
Windows 8     2012
Windows 8.1   2012
Windows 10    2014
```

How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command

```
$ paste 1.txt 2.txt
Windows 7   2009
Windows 8   2012
Windows 8.1 2012
Windows 10  2014
```